# How to fetch distinct items with all their properties in cosmos db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating an Azure Function in Typescript. One of the input bindings is an azure cosmos db container. I have a SQL query in my function.json to already filter the result. I know a lot of the results are duplicates in the sense that they have some overlapping properties, namely companyName.

Does anyone know how to only get distinct items based on the companyName property?

I already tried the following, but they all resulted in an error.

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c"
```

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT DISTINCT VALUE FROM c"
```

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT DISTINCT * ORDER BY c.companyName FROM c"
```

Comment: You cannot have `distinct *`, since you need to specify the property to check for uniqueness. Same with `distinct value` - that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Please edit to explain better: include sample data along with expected and actual output. Right now, it's unclear what you mean by "get distinct items based on companyName property" (aside from retrieving a list of unique companyName values)

Answer (score 1):

The "distinct" key word in cosmos eliminates duplicates in the query's projection. By writing

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT DISTINCT c.companyName,c.nextProp,..  FROM c"
```

Cosmos will output a new document (projection) based on your item where all the properties you list will be unique. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sort of, I would like to get back the entire object. Using an asterisk didn't seem to work. The item should be unique based on the companyName.

Comment: @rjjdv - you can't perform a `DISTINCT *` - that doesn't really make sense, since you need to specify what you want as the property.